# Excluding a certain country from a route

Tags: azure-maps

Is ability to exclude a specific countries or regions from route present? For example, I plan to go from Ukraine to France, but I don't want to go thru Poland. How can I set this in [GetRouteDirections API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/route/getroutedirections)?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it doesn't look like that's a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not of a way to specify a specific country code to avoid all together. It is possible to specify which countries to avoid tolls, and to specify custom areas to avoid using GeoJSON using the POST Route Directions API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/route/postroutedirections#request-body

Another approach is to add another waypoint in-between Ukraine and France to force the route to go around Poland. The coordinate (49.001636, 22.890648), goes through a point just below the Polish border and would put the user on a road where they would cross into Slovakia instead.

Comment: But I don't see the method PostRouteDirections in AzureMapsServices class. I use winforms and want to call this API. But only GetRouteDirections method presents

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. Its a REST service? Are you using some wrapper library?

Comment: I use standart net library AzureMapsResToolkit:.                 https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureMapsRestToolkit/

Comment: Ok, that's an open source library not created by the Azure Maps team. I don't believe they have added support for all Azure Maps services yet. Before writing code, it might be a good idea to use something like Postman to test out the service to make sure this solves your issue first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-search-for-address

Comment: Oh, yes. I don't have a problem with this. I will use httpclient and call azure maps services

Comment: PostRouteDirections does not include my areas from route. See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976135/postroutedirections-does-not-exclude-area-from-route

Comment: I saw that post and passed it on to the right team to investigate. They should be responding soon.