# PostRouteDirections does not exclude area from route

Tags: azure-maps

I used PostRouteDirections API. I got several areas to exclude from route, and put them into PostRouteDirections API. But I see that the route has not changed. 
This is example of my post request:

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/route/directions/json?subscription-key={subscription_key}&api-version=1.0&Query=47.73937,11.23431:46.05676,5.16392
```

and request body:

```
{"avoidAreas":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[47.808381,5.955894],[47.808381,6.955894],[46.808381,6.955894],[46.808381,5.955894],[47.808381,5.955894]]],[[[46.808381,5.955894],[46.808381,6.955894],[45.808381,6.955894],[45.808381,5.955894],[46.808381,5.955894]]],[[[47.808381,6.955894],[47.808381,7.955894],[46.808381,7.955894],[46.808381,6.955894],[47.808381,6.955894]]],[[[46.808381,6.955894],[46.808381,7.955894],[45.808381,7.955894],[45.808381,6.955894],[46.808381,6.955894]]],[[[47.808381,7.955894],[47.808381,8.955894],[46.808381,8.955894],[46.808381,7.955894],[47.808381,7.955894]]],[[[46.808381,7.955894],[46.808381,8.955894],[45.808381,8.955894],[45.808381,7.955894],[46.808381,7.955894]]],[[[47.808381,8.955894],[47.808381,9.955894],[46.808381,9.955894],[46.808381,8.955894],[47.808381,8.955894]]],[[[46.808381,8.955894],[46.808381,9.955894],[45.808381,9.955894],[45.808381,8.955894],[46.808381,8.955894]]],[[[47.808381,9.955894],[47.808381,10.955894],[46.808381,10.955894],[46.808381,9.955894],[47.808381,9.955894]]],[[[46.808381,9.955894],[46.808381,10.955894],[45.808381,10.955894],[45.808381,9.955894],[46.808381,9.955894]]]]}}
```

Visually it looks like this (see picture):
These polygons were transferred to avoidAreas option in request body.
Polygons satisfy the condition 160x160 km of max size, rectangles, their number is 10. Otherwise, API would have returned an error 400 in response
Why did the route remain the same?
[image]

Comment: Are you able to get this to work with other examples?

Comment: From Outi Nyman: Thanks for sharing this. We are exploring the reported behaviour and will follow-up as soon as possible.

Comment: This was my working example. Preparing another example is time consuming

Comment: This was my working example. Preparing another example is time consuming

Comment: No worries, no other example needed. @Outi Nyman is a PM in the Azure Maps team, they are looking into it. Please bear with us.

Comment: Good afternoon, do you have any news about this problem?

Comment: @Dmytro I reached out internally and they are working on this. I will keep you posted. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. It turns out that the latitude and longitude are not in the correct order.  First point is in Somalia because geojson thinks that 47.808381 is the longitude and 5.955894 is the latitude, but (the point should be in France).

GeoJSON spec is here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946  On this thread there are some suggestions on how to validate GeoJSON https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23745/how-to-validate-a-geojson

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the latitude and longitude are not in the correct order. First point is in Somalia because GeoJSON thinks that 47.808381 is the longitude and 5.955894 is the latitude, but (the point should be in France).

[image]

Comment: That is, you want to say, what for geojson need to transfer the coordinates vice versa? I copied this point (47.808381,5.955894) and paste in google - it showed France

Comment: Your function, for example, GetSearchAddressReverse, says this is France: atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/reverse/…{subscription_key}&api-version=1.0&query=47.808381,5.955894&entityType=Country And to exclude areas from the route, I have to swap the coordinates. Don't you think this introduces some confusion?